# JS - Customising html select control using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prestashop

How can I make a select element with multiple options, similar to the [Select Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBZbZ.png), have a more button-like appearance, such as the [Button Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4kiH.png)?

Can JavaScript be used to create custom button-like functionality for selecting options?

It's worth noting that the first element mentioned is automatically generated by Prestashop and is a part of the product features.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it's not part of the standard HTML specification so you'll need to write custom code (presumably both JS and CSS if you want it to look exactly like in the screenshot). Nobody here is going to write that code for you. If you make an effort and give it a shot and share the code you have written, people may be more inclined to help.

Comment: @weltschmerz That is not what I have asked for, how would you implement buttons into a select element? I can not find any documentation available in regards to such things, implementing it with JS seems impossible so far as choosing options based on button presses do not work, at least not with Prestashop as the selection does not POST.

I'm not asking for anybody to write the code out for me, I am asking for documentation or some kind of guidance.

I am aware that it requires html&css, thus asking how to inject those via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I don't know Prestashop, but if you can edit or implement JS into the code this probably can help.

If you really want to change the select element this will help you.
I will suggest to do it differently but it's your choice.

HTML (notice i disabled the select so the user will not be able to change):

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="minusBtn">-</div>
<select id="mySelect" disabled>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
  <option value="5">option5</option>
</select>
<div id="plusBtn">+</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
}
select{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
  
}
/*style the disabled select*/
select[disabled] {
  border:1px solid black !important;
  opacity:1;
  color:black;
  width:60px;
  height:20px;
  
}
#plusBtn, #minusBtn{
  cursor:pointer;
    height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  width:15px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

JS:

```
var count = 1

document.getElementById('plusBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  //first check if count is less than the max options length
  if(count < document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length){
    //increase count by 1
    count++
    //changing the select option to count
    document.getElementById('mySelect').value = count
  
    } else{
      //if count is more than the options length we want to give the last option
      document.getElementById('mySelect').value = 5
    }
 })

document.getElementById('minusBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(count > 1){
    count--
  document.getElementById('mySelect').value = count
  
    } else{
      document.getElementById('mySelect').value = 1
    }
 })
```

of course, the user can inspect the page with developer tools and change the HTML to be able to select.
In this case, you must to have back-end validation.

codepen : https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/RwabNBv

---

I EDITED the JS code according to Mad SQL answer.
So because now we will use selectedIndex, the count should equal to 0 instead of 1 because the index starts from 0.
and I compare the selected index to the length of the options if it's on maximum so now it should work even if you will add or remove options from the select.

So now it should look like this: (i didn't add the getProductAttribute())

```
var count = 0
var selectLength = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length

document.getElementById('plusBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    //increase count by 1
    count++
  //check if count is less than the max options length
  if(count < document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length){
    
    //changing the select option to count
    document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex  = count
  
    } else{
      //if count is more than the options length we want to give the last option
      count = selectLength
      document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex = selectLength -1
    }
 })

document.getElementById('minusBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    count--
  if(count > 0){
    
  document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex = count
  
    } else{
    count = 0
      document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex = 0
    }
 })
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I have tried something similar to no avail, thank you so much. <3

Comment: Welcome, hope it will solve your problem, if you need more help with this i would like to help.

Comment: For other people who might have trouble figuring this out, this answer works flawlessly but to make it truly functional with Prestashop/Thirtybees, you need to add "getProductAttribute();" after -> "document.getElementById('mySelect').value = count", also replacing value with selectedIndex works much better.

Comment: @MadSQL I edited the answer with new code with your suggestion. it works better now. notices that i didn't add the getProductAttribute().